# Ekit problem with pasting richtext copied from Ekit to other richtext

Tags: swing, copy-paste, rich-text-editor, jtextpane

Currently I am trying to find cause of the behavior that richtext from Ekit (JTextPane derivativie) cannot be pasted into other richtext editor like one in Thunderbird, Gmail, MS Word.

Tested, it doesn't work on Windows XP, Windows 7, Ubuntu.

Copying from Ekit to plain text editors works.

Reference:
[Ekit site](http://www.hexidec.com/ekit.php)

I have dump of clipboard from Ekit:

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:-1
EndHTML:-1
StartFragment:0000000111
EndFragment:0000000197
<!--StartFragment-->
<html>
  <body>
<u>o</u><i>ne
line</i>
s<b>econd line</b>
  </body>
</html>
<!--EndFragment-->
```

and from Thunderbird for comparison:

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:00000120
EndHTML:00000218
StartFragment:00000154
EndFragment:00000182
SourceURL:about:blank
<html><body>
<!--StartFragment--><b>sad</b>
nak<u>dbnask</u> <!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

Any tips where I should make changes or why it is not working?
Is position of StartFragment tag a problem or StartHTML and EndHTML values are? Maybe both?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by setting the `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` to `false` in firefox about:config